# replace special characters in a SQL String like @, before or while SQLPlus is parsing through it

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Is it possible to replace special characters in a String like @, before or while SQLPlus is parsing through it. or possibly disable the @ start command like in this ex.

```
   set define off;
DECLARE
   test CLOB
         := q'[

 @font-face
    {font-family:Wingdings;
    panose-1:5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */ ]' ;


BEGIN

INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE
VALUES(test)


END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ASCII` value instead,

```
SQL> select ascii('@') from dual;
64
```

Now, replace the `@` with `chr(64)`,

For example,

`'string one' ||chr(64)||'string two'`

Comment: sorry, i am relatively new to sql, how would you implement this into this query script?

Comment: Instead of "@", use 'chr(64)'. Rest everyhting else should be considered as string enclosed within single quotes. Like, `@font-face
    {font-family:Wingdings;` would become `chr(64)||'font-face
    {font-family:Wingdings;'`

Comment: i need a script that does all the work with out editing the html. i have everything working but that @ character. sqlplus thinks that anything that starts with @ is a file. i need a way to disable that or have a script that replaces as or before sqlplus parses through the string. can you think of any workarounds that might work?